# Conversion from Derived** to Base*const*

Tags: c++

Please read my question before linking parashift, I can google search, this is slightly different case.

This isn't allowed

```
Child **cc;
Base ** bb = cc;
```

Because you could do

```
*bb = new OtherChild;
```

But if we have

```
Child **cc;
const Base *const *const bb = cc;
```

I don't think all those const are necessary for my example, but just to be sure..

I think the minimum which should work is

```
Base *const *bb = cc;
```

Then you can't do this

```
*bb = new OtherChild;
```

So it should be safe. But why isn't it allowed?

Comment: In the second case, bb is a constant pointer to a constant pointer to Base. So *bb is a constant pointer to Base, and you cannot assign a new value to a constant pointer, so it is not allowed at least by the rule of const correctness.

Comment: The faq link does not discuss the case with totally const pointer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: The FAQ argues that the problem is not the mutability of the pointer, but the ambiguity of the conversion itself. Even when just reading from the pointer, you would get unexpected (if not undefined) behavior.

Comment: @BjörnPollex could you give an example?

Comment: @AdN Could you explain more? I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk: But I think the C++ FAQ answers your question precisely. In their example, you could turn a `car` into a `submarine`. You've added a `const`, but that doesn't really change much. You could still turn thing-A into thing-B although it isn't any such thing.

Comment: @Damon How? Please give compiling example

Comment: Scroll down to "Concluding Remarks: (in)variance of double pointers": http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html#ConcludingRemarks

Comment: @0x499602D2 But the const prevents the bad assignment from happening in your link.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You did not point what was not clear in my comment. I think we can agree that : `const Base *const *const bb` is a constant pointer to a constant pointer to Base object that is constant. And thus `*bb` is a **constant pointer** to a Base object that is constant. Or, by definition, you cannot change the value of a **constant pointer** (i.e. the address it contains is constant). This line `*bb = new OtherChild;` is nonetheless trying to change the address it contains.

Comment: @AdN Correct. That is bad behavior which is why bb cannot convert from cc in the non-const case. But in the const-case, the bad behavior is impossible, so I don't see why the conversion is disallowed.

Comment: I guess when you declare something like `Base *const *bb = cc;` you are telling to compiler that *bb is constant. So compiler can apply optimization based in a assumption that *bb wont change. But what happens when do you assign another object to *cc?

Comment: @NeilKirk: You totally missed the meaning of the diagram "(in)variance of double pointers" which 0x499602d2 linked you to.

Comment: @TomásBadan: Nope, `const` on a handle (pointer or reference) doesn't mean the target is immutable, only that this handle is a read-only view of the target.

Comment: Ben Voigt has a good answer.  But to put it briefly: you can't do this because no `Base*` object or any object with "similar type" exists to be pointed at.

Comment: @BenVoigt In the link, bad things only happen after `*rr = b;` which wouldn't be allowed with the const.

Comment: @Neil: In the link, it shows the problem, does the pointer hold the address of `Base` or the address of `Derived`?  The addresses **are not the same**.

Comment: @NeilKirk In the link of 0x499602D2 (direct anchor: http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html#DoublePointers), bad things happen even _before_ the reassignment. Here's a simplified example with all the `const`s and without reassignment, only reading a member through pointers: http://ideone.com/rj8NFI (compilation error) and http://ideone.com/ahVwaW (forced conversion): in the output, you would want the last line to be the same as the previous one, but it's not; it accesses `obj.a` instead of `obj.b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing two cases:

- The addition of `const`
- Upcasts

While formally (in computer science theory) both of these deal with subclassing, the reality is that the C++ rules for these are different, because the representation of `const T` and `T` are guaranteed to be the same, while the representations of `Base*` and `Derived*` often differ by an offset (but may be radically different when virtual inheritance is involved).

In 3.9.3, the Standard declares that

> The *cv-qualified* or *cv-unqualified* versions of a type are distinct types; however, they shall have the same representation and alignment requirements

Given:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};
Derived* pd = nullptr;
Base* pb = pd;
```

`const` can indeed by added in the way you suggest.

```
Base const* const* const cpcpcb = &pb;
Base* const* pcpb = &pb; // legal, pointer can't be changed
Base const* * ppcb = &pb; // illegal, one could try to rebind the pointer
                          // to a truly const object, then
                          // use pb to mutate the const object
```

But there is no is-a relationship between `Derived*` and `Base*`.  A conversion exists, but the `Derived*` variable does not necessarily contain the address of a `Base` object (the `Base` subobject within the `Derived` object may have a different address).  And therefore **both the line you're complaining about, and the line your question assumed was valid, are illegal**:

```
Base const* const* const cpcpcd = &pd; // error, there's no address of a Base
                                       // to be found in pd
Base* const* pcpd = &pd; // error: again, there's no address of a Base
                         // stored in pd
```

Formally, the Standard describes this in 4.10:

> A prvalue of type "pointer to cv `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to cv `B`", where `B` is a base class of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

The result of the conversion is a prvalue, it doesn't have an address, and you can't create a pointer to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate some on the rebinding pointer to a truly const object? Say hypothetically, this was allowed, what would the offending code that tries to rebind the pointer and then modify the const object look like?

Comment: @greatwolf: The code shown, plus: `const Base c; *ppcb = &c; pb->mutate();`

Comment: Typo: your last code snippet has an extra `*` before `cpcpcd` (I won't even try to suggest an edit as it's very likely to be rejected as ever...)

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks (as for my attitude, blame the reviewers: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2357763 (and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2569700 too); anyway I think the edit suggestion wouldn't even have been submitted, as IIRC it needs to be at least a 6-characters change and this was a 1-char change (2-chars with the space)...)

Comment: @gx_: Thanks for pointing that out.  The suggested edit queue isn't a good way to make changes to the meaning of code, since you need someone who's a C++ expert to verify the change.  Leaving a comment is the best solution -- you already drew the attention of a second expert, but I would certainly have made it today if it weren't already fixed.  Suggested edits work better for fixing misspelled words, etc, that don't require the reviewer to have any expertise.

Comment: @BenVoigt (You're welcome) It makes sense indeed. Thank you for giving an explicit rationale.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constraint imposed by the C++ language, because implicit conversion of pointer types is based on inheritance rules (with the exception of implicit conversion to `void *`).

That is, given the following program, the assignment is only allowed if `T` is a base of `U`:

```
T const *x;
U *y;
x = y;
```

However, in your case:

```
typedef Base *T;
typedef Child *U;
```

The relationship between `Base` and `Child` does not transfer to their pointer types. So, there is no inheritance relationship between "pointer to `Base`" and "pointer to `Child`" to allow the direct assignment you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your equation you are expecting `const` to play a bigger role than what it really has.

`const` is a qualifier, and simply put, its role is to regulate the way you access a type or a variable.

The main point is if the language itself, without even considering what is `const` or not, already regulates a given behaviour, your specific case is not that different from the one reported by that FAQ.

You are in a really simple situation, and you should probably think in much simpler terms.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why isn't it allowed? As far as I can see, it is an oversight.